# Best way to integrate Angular2+ into ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

I'm working with an old Asp.Net Framework 4 legacy system. The employer wants me to integrate Angular inside of it to use components within the currently existing site. I know it is possible, but I've only ever worked on SPAs as their own sites, never as additions.

I would like information on how to integrate Angular into Asp.Net, specifically how to add npm, how to render the components, and how to run it locally.

Any help is always appreciated.

Comment: try this https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/12/21/build-basic-web-app-with-mvc-angular

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Build a ng project within your ASP.Net project directory and then add a webpack config to compile your typescript files into JavaScript. After that just add the webpack build/watch command as part of the visual studio build events.

Long Explanation:

- Navigate to your ASP.Net project directory
- Add a ng project using the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) `ng create project_name`
- Create a webpack.config.js file in your Angular project directory and download the appropriate loaders and presets you would like to use. (I.E. typescript-loader, babel-loader, etc.)
- Set npm scripts within your packages.json file to run webpack on command
- Right click on your ASP.Net project and select *properties*->*build events*
- Type in your npm script (with the appropriate directories added) into the pre-build event. This will run webpack when you press the visual studio start button.

I think this configuration works really well, but I would like to fine tune it to make it idiot-proof. Right now it would be very easy for a new developer to screw up the webpack commands or forget to add the build event script.